# PHP cURL is making the same request twice

Tags: php, http, curl, post

I'm making a POST request to `https://api.mercadolibre.com/oauth/token` to generate a valid access token. I send a code with a few additional information to receive the token back.

I have the following request class:

```
class Request {

    private function httpRequest(
        string $method,
        string $url,
        array $headers,
        array $data=array()
    ) {
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
        ));

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

        if ($method != "GET" && $data) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        }

        if (!$response = curl_exec($curl)) {
            trigger_error(curl_error($curl));
        }

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        if (curl_errno($curl)) {
            $error = curl_errno($curl)." - ".curl_error($curl);
        }

        curl_close($curl);
        
        if (isset($error)) {
            return $error;
        }

        return $response;
    }

    public function get(
        string $url,
        array $headers,
        array $data=array()
    ) {
        if ($data) {
            $url = Utils::urlParams($url, $data);
        }

        return $this->httpRequest($method = "GET", $url, $headers);
    }

    public function post(
        string $url,
        array $headers,
        array $data=array()
    ) {
        return $this->httpRequest($method = "POST", $url, $headers, $data);
    }

    public function put(
        string $url,
        array $headers,
        array $data
    ) {
        return $this->httpRequest($method = "PUT", $url, $headers, $data);
    }
}
```

When I need to request the access token, I access the following method of ML class by using `$response = $ml->accessToken();`

```
public function accessToken() {
        if (isset($_GET["code"])) {
            $code = $_GET["code"];

            $token_headers = Utils::defaultHeaders();

            $token_data = array(
                "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
                "client_id" => $this->client_id,
                "client_secret" => $this->client_secret,
                "code" => $code,
                "redirect_uri" => $this->redirect_uri
            );

            // var_dump($this->token_url);
            // var_dump($token_headers);
            // var_dump($token_data);
            // var_dump($code);

            $response = $this->request->post(
                $this->token_url,
                $token_headers,
                $token_data
            );

            return $response;
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
```

However, I receive the following response:

```
{"cause":[],"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Error validating grant. Your authorization code or refresh token may be expired or it was already used","status":400}
```

Which makes no sense at all, since I receive a brand new code generated at the time. It could only mean that cURL is sending the POST request twice!

I tried changing `httpRequest`'s CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to false to see what it logs to, as follows:

```
private function httpRequest(
        string $method,
        string $url,
        array $headers,
        array $data=array()
    ) {
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            // CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,      // Altered!
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => false,        // Altered!
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
        ));

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

        if ($method != "GET" && $data) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        }

        if (!$response = curl_exec($curl)) {
            trigger_error(curl_error($curl));
        }

        // $response = curl_exec($curl);         // Altered!
        curl_exec($curl);                        // Altered!

        if (curl_errno($curl)) {
            $error = curl_errno($curl)." - ".curl_error($curl);
        }

        curl_close($curl);
        
        if (isset($error)) {
            return $error;
        }

        // return $response;         // Altered!
    }
```

And spot on! I receive the following message (all on the same line):

```
{"access_token":"APP_USR-731450979634979-062614-76a6db201965f6c18c1108cebc48fb1d-1405568857","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":21600,"scope":"offline_access read write","user_id":1405568857,"refresh_token":"TG-6499d6c7eea12900019aba4d-1405568857"}
{"cause":[],"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Error validating grant. Your authorization code or refresh token may be expired or it was already used","status":400}
```

It means I'm actually receiving the token I need, however it gets overthrown by the failing second request.

I'm **100% sure** I'm only executing the request method *once*. I'm getting so frustrated since I tried all sorts of things.

I need to set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true so I can access the token to store it afterwards, however the only return I receive is telling me that the code I'm using is expired (which isn't at first!).

Please, can you help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling it twice:

```
if (!$response = curl_exec($curl)) {
    trigger_error(curl_error($curl));
}

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

The code in the `if (!$response = curl_exec($curl))` line makes the call, assigns the result to `$response`, then checks the result. If that response in an error, `trigger_error` is called. The next line then repeats the call to `curl_exec` with the same parameters but doesn't care about the result.